# ASMX Web Service - Client listening to CallBack url

Tags: jquery, web-services, callback, asmx, jquery-callback

I have an asmx web service that I must consume passing him a callback url. Webservice use this url to make some http get passing some parameters in querystring with some info i need (Percentage,status, etcetc)...

I can consume the webservice but I'm not able to get callbacks.

I'm using c# to call it and I would like to listen to the service call-backs with jQuery...

Comment: can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Simply added reference to web service,call web service method passing parameter it needs and no more  (server side)...for example var result = myWebService.Go("par1","par2","http//:urlforcallback.com");

Comment: Please be more clear. How are you consuming the service? How do you expect to get  callback on the client?

Comment: The "Add Web Reference" takes place on the server. You're expecting a callback on the client? Why would that work? Please show the code in the service that "calls back" the client, and show the code in the client that "listens" for the callback.

Comment: Yes I don't know how to use that url!

Comment: OK I figured the behaviour out...I call a web service giving him a url for callbacks. for example...www.mysite.com/pageforcallback. So web service makes some httpGet to this url with some parameters in query string I have to manage. So any suggestion  will be very appreciated...